# OpenVino >2020.3 Version

Tags: version, openvino, movidius

How could I download the 2020.3 version of OpneVino, given that the versions on the site stop at 2021
(https://github.com/movidius/ncsdk#intel-movidius-neural-compute-sdk)?

I tried to download a specific version of OpenVino (2020.3), but it can no longer be found already compiled on this site  https://storage.openvinotoolkit.org/repositories/openvino/packages/.
I would like someone to help me find a download or send me the link to their already compiled version.

Answer (score 0):

OpenVINO™ Toolkit version 2020.3 Long Term Support (LTS) package is no longer available for download. The current available LTS Releases are for OpenVINO™ Toolkit version 2022.3 (LTS) and version 2021.4.2 (LTS).

Currently, the only way to install OpenVINO™ version 2020.3 is by building the OpenVINO™ Inference Engine from GitHub. Here is the link to build OpenVINO™ Inference Engine version 2020.3:
https://github.com/openvinotoolkit/openvino/blob/2020.3.0/build-instruction.md#build-openvino-inference-engine

On another note, the link you've provided is related to Intel® Neural Compute Stick 2 (Intel® NCS2) and as such, we'd suggest for you to install OpenVINO™ Toolkit 2022.3.1 (LTS) since it includes support for NCS2 and provides additional features and bug fixes as compared to OpenVINO™ 2020.3.

Comment: I have already tried to compile the build from the link you sent me, but towards the end it gives me an error. In fact I was looking for an already completed build.

Comment: Please share the error message you've encountered when building the Inference Engine. Please also check that your system fits the [System Requirements](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/developer/articles/release-notes/openvino/2020.html#inpage-nav-10) for OpenVINO™ 2020.3.

As previously mentioned, OpenVINO™ Toolkit version 2020.3 Long Term Support (LTS) package is no longer available for download thus you'll need to build the OpenVINO™ Inference Engine from GitHub.